# How to generate/print bill in web2py?

Tags: web2py, foreign-key-relationship

I am doing a sample app in web2py.
Which involves Customer, Product and Bill as shown below

```
db=DAL('sqlite://Navale.db')
db = DAL(lazy_tables=True)

STATE= ('Andaman and Nicobar Islands','Andhra Pradesh','Arunachal Pradesh','Assam','Bihar','Chandigarh','   Chhattisgarh','Dadra and Nagar Haveli','Daman and Diu','Delhi','Goa','Gujrat','Haryana','Himachal Pradesh','Jammu and Kashmir','Jharkhand','    Karnataka','Kerala','Lakshadeep','Madhya Pradesh','Maharashtra','Manipur','Meghalaya','Mizoram','Nagaland','Odisha','Puducherry','Punjab','Rajasthan','Sikkim','Tamil Nadu','Telangana','Tripuru',' Uttar Pradesh','Uttarakhand','West Bengal')

db.define_table('Customer',
                Field('Customer_ID', type='id', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                Field('Customer_Type', requires=IS_IN_SET(['Retail','Local'])),
                Field('Name', type='string', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                Field('Contact_Number', type='integer', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                Field('Address', type='string'),
                Field('City', type='string', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                Field('State', requires=IS_IN_SET(STATE)),
                Field('PIN', type='integer', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY())
                )
db.define_table('Product',
                Field('Product_ID',  requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                Field('Product_Name'),
                Field('Category', requires=IS_IN_SET(['Gents', 'Ladies', 'Kids'])),
                Field('Rate', type='double'))
db.define_table ('Bill',
                 Field('Bill_ID', type='id', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                 Field('Date', type='datetime'),
                 Field('Customer_ID', db.Customer),
                 Field('Customer_Name', db.Customer),
                 Field('Total_cost', type='double'))
```

When I try to add customer name in 'Bill' it is showing error

[image]

> I want to generate/print a bill which has customer details , product
>   informations (like product name, product type, quantity, price), and
>   total price of all products.

Help me.

Note :- Here Bill consists of dynamic values of Products. That means Bill can have 1/2/3/.../n  number of products.

Answer (score 3):

In web2py, a reference field stores the primary key of the referenced table, which is the integer "id" field of the referenced table. So, it does not make sense to define a "Customer_Name" field as a reference field (presumably such a field would store a name, yet reference fields store integer IDs). The "Customer_ID" field is already a reference to the "Customer" table -- you do not need an additional reference to the "Customer" table. So, you should simply drop the "Customer_Name" field.

Note, you can add a "format" attribute to the "Customer" table:

```
db.define_table('Customer', ..., format='%(name)s')
```

Now, any time you define a field that references the "Customer" table, such as:

```
    Field('Customer_ID', db.Customer)
```

the reference field will get (a) a default form widget that shows customer names (even though the associated "Customer" record IDs will be inserted in the database), and (b) a default "represent" attribute that displays the customer name rather than the customer ID in read-only forms and the grid.

If you need to access customer details in conjunction with a bill or set of bills, you can do so via a [join](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Inner-joins). You can also take advantage of web2py's built-in [recursive selects](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Recursive-selects) feature.

Comment: How to derive customer information from Customer_ID in bill ?

Comment: See edited answer. You can use a join or recursive select.